# How to update the values of Collections with parameters using MONGODB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I´m having problems to understand the update process in MongoDB using Java.

I have two entitys in the same Collections.
Example:

Purchase:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59805e3990fee524fca26de3"), "Nome do Cliente" : "               Oiros", "Nome do Produto" : "    Camisola", "Quantidade" : 2, "Total" : 70 }
```

Product:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980678290fee53300ab153b"), "Nome do Produto" : "               Camisola", "Preço" : "        35", "Quantidade" : 100 }
```

I want to update all the products quantity where product and purchase have the same product name using MongoDb.

After Purchase:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980678290fee53300ab153b"), "Nome do Produto" : "               Camisola", "Preço" : "        35", "Quantidade" : 98 }
```

Comment: it's not clear, What is it that you want to update? Show the expected result

Comment: @abdul i want to update the quantity of products, like if the client purchase one product, i want to update the stock, you understand?